# Section bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

What is the best way create a bibliography for separate sections within a document? I am using `biblatex`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Please refer to Section 3.14.3 *Multiple Bibliographies* of the `biblatex` documentation. The basic idea is to use the `refsection` environment for each bibliographical unit and the `\printbibliography` command inside each `refsection` environment. Notice that you will have to compile (through bibTeX, for example) the auxiliary `.aux` files that will be created for every `refsection` environment.

Here's an schematic document (`test.tex`) to produce a bibliography for each chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\begin{refsection}

\cite{goossens93}, \cite{lamport94}, \cite{rahtz89}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}

\begin{refsection}
\cite{greenwade93}, \cite{patashnik88}, \cite{knuth79}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

the database `biblio.bib`:

```
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"

}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
           url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Tex and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = "1979",
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}

@book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "Latex: A Document Preparation System",
    year = "1994",
    edition = "Second",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{patashnik88,
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "{B}ib{T}e{X}ing.  Documentation for General {B}ib{T}e{X} users",
    year = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX
distribution"
}

@techreport{rahtz89,
    author = "Sebastian Rahtz",
    title = "A Survey of {T}ex and graphics",
    year = "1989",
    institution = "Department of Electronics and Computer Science",
    address = "University of Southampton, UK",
    number = "CSTR 89-7"
}
```

You need to compile the example in the following way:

```
pdflatex test
bibtex test1-blx
bibtex test2-blx
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

Comment: I've been using an IDE which doesn't figure that out. When I try from the command line, there is no `biblatex` command. Where should I look for that? Or is it a parameter for `bibtex`?

Comment: @Nate Glenn: Sorry for that! It was a mistake; I fixed it now.

Comment: @Nate Glenn: or maybe have a look at biber instead of bibtex, ie `biber test1-blx` and `biber test2-blx`

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina: Works great, thanks. Do you know any IDEs that pick up on that automatically? I can do it with the command line, but I'd rather just use the IDE.

Comment: By the way, biber processes all refsections in one pass so you just need:

pdflatex test
biber test
pdflatex test

Comment: @Nate Glenn: no, I don't know how to configure some IDE to automate the compilation procedure; I use the command line.

Comment: @PLK: I think I am gonna give biber a try. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I've just checked and only for the sake for semplicity I would let you know that the reference section is now 3.13.3 in the Biblatex Documentation