# latex/bibtex problem to do a single bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

Is it possible to do an organized bibliography with LaTeX and BibTeX ?
Only a bibliography without any text but some section, subsection etc with BibTeX references ? I mean without having the references at the end but in the differents sections. I know the command `\nocite*` and the `multibib` package but it doesnt work for that.

Comment: Judging from the upvotes, other people apparently understand the question. But I don’t. Could you please try to clarify what you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Section Bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19326/3954).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do such a bibliography. It is very easy using the biblatex package. With this package, it is possible to define refsections (chapter 3.5.4 of the biblatex documentation), in which you will do the citations, and print a specific bibliography refering to this refsection wherever you want, in particular at the end of each refsection which could be chapters, sections, parts or whatever piece of text you want...
with a `\printbibliography[section=number of the refsection]` command.

EDIT: if you really don't want to use biblatex (for whatever reason), you can use the chapterbib package, but it is less flexible than biblatex.