# Is it possible to have back references after each chapter with a single main.bib file?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, bibtex, subdividing, back-referencing

I'm using LaTeX + BibTeX to write my dissertation. I have one separate `.tex` file for each chapter. And I'll generate one bibliography for each chapter. But all the references are from the same file (`main.bib`).

So, there are many situations in which different chapters will cite the same reference. Thus, one reference can appear more than once in the bibliographies of the whole dissertation (but in different chapters). I'd like to use back references from the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). I'm just wondering whether it would be possible to do so?

```
% chapter 1
Bibliography
[1]. A and B, Nature, 1991. 15, 20.
...

% chapter 2
Bibliography
...
[3]. A and B, Nature, 1991. 55, 67.
...
```

Comment: I think the answer is no. If you have just one `main.bib` file, then from the example you've provided, in Chapter 2 you will get the page numbers 15 and 20 being back-referenced as well.

Comment: I'm just too lazy (sorry) to read the 219 pages documentation of http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html
but maybe that package can help you.

Comment: The package `biblatex` is the best way. The documentation is very long but in section *3.10.3 Multiple Bibliographies* you find an example which explains the syntax. I don't want to copy and paste the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Section Bibliographies](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19326/section-bibliographies)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel -- it's not quite a duplicate because this OP is using bibtex rather than biblatex.

Comment: @Mico: That's the reason the word `possible` is used ;-). The next one -- `biblatex` is a package which also works with the bibtex. Up to now nobody knows what the op uses.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel -- I suppose (almost) everything is `possible`. But, given that the OP used the word "BibTeX" in the very first sentence, I was placing (`possibly` inappropriately) low odds on the `possibility` that he/she was looking for a biblatex solution. ;-)

Comment: @yCalleecharan -- please see my answer that provides a full MWE. It uses a single `.bib` file, but doesn't generate spurious additional back references. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You may want to try using the `chapterbib` package. (There's also the `bibunits` package, but since you state that your chapters are contained in separate `.tex` files, it may be easiest to proceed with the `chapterbib` package.) This package is designed to create bibliographies separately for each chapter, regardless of the number of bib files you have.

The following MWE demonstrates the usage of this package with a very basic setup. It loads the packages `natbib`, `chapterbib`, `hyperref`, and `backref` as well as the bibliography style file `plainnat.bst`. The file `demo.bib` contains:

```
@article{abadir:1993a,
    author       = "Karim M. Abadir",
    title        = "{OLS} bias in a nonstationary autoregression",
    journal      = "Econometric Theory",
    year         = 1993,
    volume       = 9,
    number       = 1,
    pages        = "81--93"
}
```

The "chapter" files `demo-1.tex`, `demo-2.tex`, and `demo-3.tex` each contain (they're identical):

```
\chapter{Hello}  
\citet{abadir:1993a}\clearpage\citet{abadir:1993a}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{demo}
```

(Note that each chapter issues two citation calls.) The overall driver file, `demo.tex`, contains:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib,chapterbib,hyperref,backref}
\begin{document}
\include{demo-1}
\include{demo-2}
\include{demo-3}
\end{document}
```

Run (pdf)latex twice on `demo.tex`; run bibtex once each on `demo1.tex`,  `demo2.tex`, and `demo3.tex`; and run (pdf)latex twice more on `demo.tex`. The compiled document, `demo.pdf`, should contain 11 pages (4 pages each for chapters 1 and 2, and 3 pages for chapter 3). The typeset bibliography of chapter 3, on page 11, looks like this:

[image]

The back references for the bibliographies of chapters 1 and 2 should be "pages 1, 2" and "pages 5, 6", respectively.

You can, of course, adjust the appearance of the back references; see the manual of the `backref` package for details.

Comment: The OP has specified that he/she wants to use `hyperref`s back-referencing feature. Given [this](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2009-November/013746.html) post at `texhax` describing some incompatibilities between back-referencing and the `chapterbib` package, it would be better if you added a MWE which demonstrates that your proposed solutions work.

Comment: @lockstep: Please see the attached MWE. Given that the post you reference is more than two years old, it's (maybe?) not a surprise that whatever bugs surfaced back then seem to have been fumigated. :-)

Answer (score 7):

The following solution is based on `biblatex` and provides what you want: It uses the `biblatex` concept of *segments* (see §3.5.4 of the `biblatex` manual) to define a context for citation tracking. By the `refsegment=chapter` class option every chapter becomes a segment on its own; at the end of each chapter the segment-specific bibliography is printed; at the end of the document a chapter with the full bibliography is printed. All this works well with back-references, for which `biblatex` provides built-in support by a dedicated class option.

[image: C1]

[image: C2]

[image: Full]

The only (possible) issue might be that the back-references are always complete. This means that if you cite a source in both, Chapter 1 and Chapter 2, the back-ref list of the Chapter 1 bibliography will also contain the entry for the respective page in Chapter 2.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[defernums=true, hyperref, backref, refsegment=chapter]{biblatex}
% Define typesetting of references heading
\defbibheading{references}[References]{% 
  \section*{#1}% 
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}

% Define typesetting of bibliography heading
\defbibheading{bibliography}[Complete Bibliography]{% 
  % define as above if you want to have this numbered as well:
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
  \markboth{#1}{#1}%
}


% The filtecontent package is just used to create an example .bib-File
% automatically out of the following (for the MWE)
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

% The bibtex database to use (mybib for mybib.bib)
\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{First Chapter}

Some more text \autocite{A01,B02}.

% print the segment-specific bibliography (using the references style 
% defined above for the heading
\printbibliography[heading=references,segment=\therefsegment]

\chapter{Second Chapter}

Some text \autocite{A01,C03}.

\printbibliography[heading=references,segment=\therefsegment]


% print the full bibliography (using the bibliography style 
% defined above for the heading above
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he would like to have back references only of the specific chapter he is in, not the other ones (before or after). Your solution, IMHO, does not tackle that particulat issue.

Comment: @Martigan: Hm... in that case one could try to track the page range of each chapter (`zref`?) and use that information to customize the processing of the biblatex-internal `pageref` field that holds the backref pages:  `\DeclareListFormat{pageref}{ print only pages within chapter range }`. Any takers? I am currently not able to invest the time to test this.

Comment: `\begin{document}` ended by `\end{refsegment}`. :D

Comment: @pushpen.paul: Thanks for spotting, I have fixed the bug.