# Conflict of backrefalt for bibliographies at end of each chapter (using natbib and chapterbib)

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, natbib, subdividing, back-referencing

I want to have the bibliographies at end of each chapter and still have the cross-reference on the reference list stating "Cited on pages:" using `natbib` and `chapterbib` packages.

To compile the document I am using a `.bat` file as postprocessor as instructed here: ["References by Chapter".](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4647) Please also use the referred process or

```
pdflatex Sample.tex
bibtex Sample.tex
bibtex chp01
bibtex chp02
[...]
pdflatex Sample.tex
pdflatex Sample.tex
```

to compile the PDF.

Please see the example files below.

**Sample.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{chp01.tex}
    \blinddocument

    \cite{lamport94}
    \cite{knuth84}

    \begingroup
    \let\chapter\section
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{sample}
    \endgroup
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{chp02.tex}
    \blinddocument

    \cite{knuth84}

    \begingroup
    \let\chapter\section
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References} 
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{sample}
    \endgroup
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
    @book{knuth84,
        author    = {{D}onald {E}. {K}nuth},
        title     = {{T}he \TeX book},
        year      = {1984},
        series    = {{C}omputers and typesetting},
        volume    = {A},
        publisher = {{A}ddison-{W}esley}
    }

    @book{lamport94,
        author    = {{L}eslie {L}amport},
        title     = {\LaTeX\ -- {A} {D}ocument {P}reparation {S}ystem},
        year      = {1994},
        publisher = {{A}ddison-{W}esley},
        edition   = {{S}econd}
    }
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[square,comma,numbers,sort,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[hyperindex,pagebackref=true,pdfusetitle,pdfa=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{plainpages=false,colorlinks,breaklinks,linktocpage,hypertexnames=true,naturalnames=false}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue} 

%%%%%%% Backref
\renewcommand*{\backrefsep}{, }
\renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{ and~}
\renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{ and~}
\renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}   % empty definition for \backrefalt to be used, i.e. disable standard 
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%

\vspace{-1.0mm}
    \scriptsize\itshape\mbox{
        \ifnum#1=1 %
         \\(Cited on page~%
        \else
            \\(Cited on pages~%
        \fi
        #2)
        }}

\begin{document}
    \include{chp01}
    \include{chp02}
\end{document}
```

The file is beeing compiled, but the reference page links of "Cited on pages:" are missing (see the figure below).

Is it possible a patch or workaround to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer from the post

[Is it possible to have back references after each chapter with a single main.bib file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36208/is-it-possible-to-have-back-references-after-each-chapter-with-a-single-main-bib)

solved my problem. It shows how to use packages `natbib`, `chapterbib`, `hyperref`, and `backref` to back reference the pages where citations appeared.

Also, the commands should be

```
pdflatex Sample.tex
bibtex chp01
bibtex chp02
[...]
pdflatex Sample.tex
pdflatex Sample.tex
```

When I did `bibtex Sample.tex`, it didn't work.