# Bibliography appearing incorrectly, using refsection

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, subdividing

After reading: [Section bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19326/section-bibliographies) carefully I am still stuck and frustrated. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{document}
.
.
.
\section{publications}
\begin{refsection}
\cite{kb}, \cite{co}, \cite{bn}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
```

I compile xelatex>bibtex>xelatex>xelatex but bibliography fails to appear
Here is one of the 3 bibliographies

```
@article{bn,
  author    = {Evripidis Bampis and
               Giorgio Lucarelli and
           Ioannis Nemparis},
   title     = {Improved Approximation Algorithms for the Non-preemptive
           Speed-scaling Problem},
   journal   = {CoRR},
   volume    = {abs/1209.6481},
   year      = {2012},
   ee        = {http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6481},
   bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
}
```

And here is what I get:
[image: result]![enter image description here]

The friggeri.cls contains nothing for bibliography cause I erased that part. The code I posted on top is from my cv_10.tex file and mybib.bib file. Please stick to the refsection usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I called the bib file mybib.bib and the tex file prawf.tex:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{publications}
\begin{refsection}
\cite{bn}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

I ran

```
xelatex prawf.tex
bibtex prawf1-blx
xelatex prawf.tex
xelatex prawf.tex
```

Note that you must run bibtex on each section bbl file produced since you are using bibtex with refsections. Hence the run on prawf1-blx rather than on prawf.

Comment: I do exactly as you say but still the problem is not solved. After the first xelatex run on cv_10.tex I get again the result posted top and even with bibtex on the -blx nothing changes. I tried too
    xelatex prawf.tex
    bibtex prawf1-blx
    bibtex prawf.tex
    xelatex prawf.tex
    xelatex prawf.tex
But in that occasion nothing appears

Comment: Without seeing the output in e.g. the log file it is hard to guess what might be wrong in that case. What version of biblatex, bibtex etc. do you have?