# Chapter Citations are not being referenced in Dissertation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, chapters, chapterbib

I am writing my dissertation with different chapters and articles referenced in each Chapter. I have one .bib file which contains all the articles, books but I want them to be referenced chapter wise. However, this is not working. (The compilation shows no error) I am trying the following:

My main file looks like:

```
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Figures/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Thesis Title}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Author Name}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref,bm,amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\modulolinenumbers[250]
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelformat=parens,labelsep=quad,skip=3pt]{caption}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3B1}{$\alpha$}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref,bm,amsmath}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx




\title{Thesis Title}
\author{Sauradeep Bhowmick}
\date{\today}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybibfile.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\input{TitlePage}
    
\input{Abstract}
    
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \listoffigures
    
    \listoftables
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \input{chapters/Introduction}
    

    \appendix
    \chapter{Appendix Title}
    \input{chapters/Appendix}

    
    %% A list of publications can be created using this approach
    \begin{refsection}
        \nocite{Moes,Anderson}   % .bib keys of your own publications
        
        \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={List of Publications}]
    \end{refsection}
    
\end{document}
```

The Introduction file looks like:

```
\begin{refsection}
    \section{Section Heading}
    Here's another citation!  \nocite{Rabczuk2007}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{refsection}
```

My .bib file looks like this:

```
@Article{Rabczuk2007,
    author="Rabczuk, Timon
    and Bordas, Stephane
    and Zi, Goangseup",
    title="A three-dimensional meshfree method for continuous multiple-crack initiation, propagation and junction in statics and dynamics",
    journal="Computational Mechanics",
    year="2007",
    month="Aug",
    day="01",
    volume="40",
    number="3",
    pages="473--495",
}

@Article{Moes,
    author ="Nicolas Moës and John Dolbow and Ted Belytschko",
    title = "A finite element method for crack growth without remeshing",
    journal = "International Journal for Numerical Methods in Engineering",
    volume = {46},
    number = {1},
    pages = {131-150},
    keywords = {finite elements, fracture},
    doi = {10.1002/(SICI)1097-0207(19990910)46:1<131::AID-NME726>3.0.CO;2-J},
    url = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0207%2819990910%2946%3A1%3C131%3A%3AAID-NME726%3E3.0.CO%3B2-J},
}

@book{Anderson,
    author = {Ted L. Anderson},
    title = {Fracture Mechanics:
    Fundamentals and Applications},
    date = {24 June 2005},
    edition = {3rd Edition},
    publisher = {CRC Press},
    location = {Boca Raton},
    pages = {640 pages},
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1201/9781420058215},
}
```

The issue currently is not chapterwise citation, I cannot even list the refences in the main page. Please help me debug the issue with this.

Comment: Please note that the code shown so far in the question is not complete (every LaTeX document should have a `\documentclass`), contains references to files we don't have `\input{chapters/Appendix}` and is in general quite likely to contain lots of code that is not relevant to the question. It would be great if you could reduce your code to a minimal, yet compilable example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: For now all I can say is that since you use `refsection`s with the BibTeX backend (`backend=bibtex,`) instead of the recommended Biber backend (`backend=biber,` and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864), you need to run BibTeX only multiple auxiliary files (this is explained in the `.log` file). If you normally only run BibTeX on the main file or your editor does that for you, you need to change your workflow. (With Biber it would be enough to run it once on the main document.) ...

Comment: ... See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128196/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/151338/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518220/35864