# Creating a list of references different from those cited in the text

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, bibliographystyle

So I have a document in which I cite references and generate a bibliography section. So far so good.

Now I want to add another section with a selected list of references which are not cited in the text.

Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/164672

Comment: thanks a lot ! I'll have a look

Comment: I checked and couldn't find a solution :(

Comment: So you don't want a separate section with ALL references that are not cited at all, but only some references? I would suggest to use the `refsection` environment. Try this: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19326/section-bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19326/section-bibliographies)

Comment: It's even more complex than this. In the separate section, I want references from another list and these references are not cited in the text